# RVM & Home brew issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rvm, homebrew

I recently opened an old project within my terminal and recieved the following message

```
 ruby-2.0.0-p598 is not installed.
 To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p598'
```

I then ran rvm install rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p598 and recieved this message

```
 Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
 No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p598.
 Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
 Checking requirements for osx.
 /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
 /usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
 ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
 Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I then ran brew doctor and recieved this message

```
 /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
 /usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

What is going on here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R username:group /usr/local  try brew doctor again.

Comment: This would be much better if you put the command into a code block separate from your other instructions.

Comment: What will this do? @Ajean